# How can i get the listening start time with speechRecognition in c#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm doing project in C# that read from a video file and convert it to subtitle text, but i want to get the start time for each text line so it can be shown in the video at the right time, i tried the AudioPosition but it not working well, is there a away to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace project
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    string[] tokens;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "WAV|*.wav";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {           
        }

        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        Grammar gr = new DictationGrammar();
        sre.LoadGrammar(gr);
        sre.SetInputToWaveFile(@openFileDialog1.FileName);

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var recText = sre.Recognize();
                sb.Append(recText.Audio.AudioPosition + " * ");
                textBox4.Text = sb.ToString();



        tokens = sb.ToString().Split('@');
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            textBox2.AppendText(tokens.Length.ToString());
            textBox2.AppendText(i+" - "+tokens[i]);
            textBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

        }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `sre`, `sbSilence`, and `recText`? In other words - we need more code. Also, what libraries are you using?

Comment: Sorry, and thank you for your response, i edit on the code, recText is where the text can be saved and i tried to get the started time by using recText.Audio.AudioPosition but i think i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Much better! Does this question help you at all? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8392026/375375

Comment: unfortunately it's not.